# How to inject MessageSource resource bundle with Spring?

Tags: java, spring, internationalization

Hi have two different message bundles. How can I directly inject them into a spring bean `MessageSource`?

The following does not work:

```
@Resource(name = "${messages_one_EB.properties}")
private MessageSource messageSourceOne;

@Resource(name = "${messages_two_EN.properties}")
private MessageSource messageSourceTwo;
```

Result: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'messages_one_EB.properties'`

Probably it works similar, but how? I could not find any example in the docs.

Both bundles are placed under `src/main/resources/`

Comment: use `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource`

Comment: Why would you need 2 `MessageSource` instances? Just specify a pattern for both in a single `MessageSource`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you can declare 2 different beans for your message sources and then inject them by name:

```
@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource1() {
    final ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();

    messageSource.setBasename("classpath:i18n/messages1");
    messageSource.setFallbackToSystemLocale(false);
    messageSource.setCacheSeconds(0);

    return messageSource;
}

@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource2() {
    final ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();

    messageSource.setBasename("classpath:i18n/messages2");
    messageSource.setFallbackToSystemLocale(false);
    messageSource.setCacheSeconds(0);

    return messageSource;
}
```

Then in your class:

```
@Resource(name = "messageSource1")
private MessageSource messageSourceOne;
@Resource(name = "messageSource2")
private MessageSource messageSourceTwo;
```

Comment: Maybe I should add that all bundles are placed in `src/main/resources`. The correct path to use in this case is to just omit the classpath. Thus: `setBasename(i18n/messages2)`.